# Digital signature using java differs between 2 JDK's: 1.6 and 1.7

Tags: java, digital-signature

I'm using SHA1withRSA algorithm to sign a text file but when I create the signature using for example java JDK 1.6 and trying to verify the same file on the same machine but on JDK 1.7 it becomes not verified, please help here is my code to sign

```
char[] pwd = "XXXXXX".toCharArray();
KeyStore ks = getKeyStore(args[0], pwd);
//KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry pkEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("test", "abc123".toCharArray());                PrivateKey priv = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey("wps", pwd);                PublicKey pub = ks.getCertificate("wps").getPublicKey();                //PrivateKey priv = pair.getPrivate();                //PublicKey pub = pair.getPublic();                Signature rsa =     Block quote
Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");

rsa.initSign(priv);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[1]);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
//BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new         InputStreamReader(dis));
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis,"UTF8"));
String strLine;
String strSign = "";
int len = 0;
boolean alreadySigned = false;
while ((strLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    len +=strLine.getBytes("UTF8").length;
    //if (strLine.indexOf("-") > -1) {
    if (strLine.startsWith("-")) {
        while ((strLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            strSign += strLine;
        }

    }

}
System.out.println("Number of bytes:" + len);
fis.close();

fis = new FileInputStream(args[1]);
dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
//bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8"));

while ((strLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    //if (strLine.indexOf("-") > -1) {
    if (strLine.startsWith("-")) {
        System.out.println("Substring" + strLine.substring(0,strLine.length() - 1));
        //rsa.update(strLine.substring(0,strLine.length() - 1).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        rsa.update(strLine.substring(0,strLine.length() - 1).getBytes());


    }else
        //rsa.update(strLine.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        rsa.update(strLine.getBytes());
}
fis.close();

realSig = rsa.sign();
FileOutputStream sigfos = new FileOutputStream(args[1], true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(sigfos, "UTF8");
String base64 = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(realSig);
String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
//wr.write(lineSep.getBytes());
wr.write(lineSep);
//sigfos.write("[Signature]".getBytes());
//sigfos.write(lineSep.getBytes());
base64=base64.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"),"");
//sigfos.write(base64.getBytes());
//sigfos.flush();
//sigfos.close();
wr.write(base64);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

and here is the code that verify

```
realSig = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(strSign);


//Verify
rsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");

rsa.initVerify(pub);

fis = new FileInputStream(args[1]);
//dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,"UTF8"));
//bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
strLine = null;
while ((strLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    //if (strLine.indexOf("-") > -1) {
    if (strLine.startsWith("-")) {
        rsa.update(strLine.substring(0,strLine.length() - 1).getBytes());
        break;
    }

    rsa.update(strLine.getBytes());
}
;
fis.close();
```

Please advise how can I verify signature on all jdk versions

Comment: Your code contains a lot of character-to-byte translation and vice versa. Have you compared signing and verifying of a well-defined byte array instead?

Comment: Can you show me small example please

Comment: E.g. always sign and verify he message `byte[] test = new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5};`.

Comment: Is the file that you're signing binary? If so then you can't use StreamReaders. You should rather use FileInputStream and BufferedInputStream directly.